# How to change a single element in a matrix intialized by list of list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

First I initialized a matrix using list of list with one in every element
I tried changing this first element in the matrix by assigning it to 2

```
chessboard=[[1]*8]*8
chessboard[0][0] = 2
for r in chessboard:
  print(r)
```

The output what i get

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

what I actually expect is

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: `chessboard = [[2] + [1] * 7] * 8`

Comment: You added the same reference 8 times. you need to create individual lists: `chessboard=[[1 for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]`

Comment: @RoadRunner - superp - now you only have the 1s as "same reference" ? or does the  concattenation change that?